# Display in a toast array list

Tags: java, android

How do i display my array list in a toast..
This is the code i have, but it's not displaying the full items in the array..what is my problem?

```
public static  EditText txt1;
String ag;
public static ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();
String playerlist[];

/** Called when the activity is first created. 
 * @param Public */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, Object Public) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    // edittext1 or textview1
    txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ag = txt1.getText().toString();

    //add more items button
    Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (txt1.getText().length() != 0) {
                String ag = "Current Added Players:," + txt1.getText().toString() + txt1.getText().toString();
                playerList.add(ag);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Screen2.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("Stringarray", playerList);
                //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer incase someone runs into the same problem: add the the "player= txt1....." inside the button click itself not outside

```
     //add more items button
    Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            player = txt1.getText().toString();
            if (txt1.getText().toString().length() !=0){
                playerList.add(player);
                txt1.setText(""); 
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), playerList + " ",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If your ArrayList is of Strings or of any wrapper class objects, then you can follow this

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("Hello");
a.add("World"); //similarly any other add statements
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), a+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

No need to convert to array or iterate through the list, because when the list is of String or wrapper class objects, then their toString() methods will return the value instead of hexadecimal logical address.

So in this case you will get a toast message showing

```
[Hello,World,...other elements what is stored in the arraylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use List.toArray(playerList), and then loop over the list to make a long string and toast that

```
String[] playerArray = (String[]) playerList.toArray();
String playerToast = playerArray[0];
for(int i=1; i<playerArray.length(); i++){
    playerToast += " ";
    playerToast += playerArray[i];
}
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), playerToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Why do you need converting to array?
    `String playerToast = playerList.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < playerList.size(); i++){
        playerToast += " ";
        playerToast += playerList.get(i);
    }`

Comment: 1. Sergey has a good point, you don't need to convert the list to an array using `List.get(i)` although I would have used a string array to begin with

2. what happened to your code from yesterday, where you cleared the EditText box `txt1.setText("")` every time you pressed the button and added to the `playerList`.

3. Yawus is right, loop over the toast would be visually more aesthetic than a very long toast, that's easy enough
`for(int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++){ Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), playerList.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}`

Comment: did you get it to work? can you please select an answer if any helped?

Comment: sorry saw this now...am working on it now and will post the code up of what it says can comes up with ..thanks ya'll

Comment: The toast is showing blank so now i don't know where i went wrong.. `    //add more items button
     Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             if (txt1.getText().length() != 0) {
              playerList.add(ag);
                  for(int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++){
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), playerList.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Screen2.class) startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: @Mark, am getting a blank toast..no input from the user is being displayed

Comment: this code crushes my emu
     `Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
                      playerList.add(ag);
                                        String[] playerArray = (String[]) playerList.toArray();
              String playerToast = playerArray[0];
              for(int i=1; i<playerArray.length; i++){
                  playerToast += " ";
                  playerToast += playerArray[i];}   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), playerToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line of code

```
String ag = "Current Added Players:," +txt1.getText().toString() + txt1.getText().toString() ;
```

Every time you push whatever button you've set that listener to, the variable `ag` is assigned the above value. The Toast you're using has `ag` set as its message so the Toast will always display

```
"Current Added Players:," +txt1.getText().toString() + txt1.getText().toString()
```

There are several ways to use Toast to display the contents of your ArrayList:

One way is to use a for loop and assign the contents of your ArrayList into a single String, although this will result in an enormously large Toast for larger ArrayLists.

The second way is to use a for loop to display a Toast message for each entry in your ArrayList. Something along the lines of

```
 for(int i, i < playerList.length, i++) {
      Toast.makeText(this, playerList[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           .show();
 }
```

Comment: it works i just had to put the string declaration inside the button click